Image from Asset not rendering in NSPrintOperation
In SwiftUI, I want to print a view with NSPrintOperation. The view is coded as follows:
struct Preview: View {
            var width: CGFloat
             
            var body: some View {
                
                VStack(
                    alignment: .leading,
                    content: {
                        Text("MyText")
                            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                            .italic()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("MathGenie"))
                            .padding()
                        Image("MyImage")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .background(Color(.yellow))
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .leading)
                        Image(systemName: "printer")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .leading)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                )
            }
        }

It contains an image from the asset catalog. The Text (:) and Image(systemName: "printer") are displayed correctly and the image is displayed correctly, if I embed the view in a window.
The NSPrintOperation is triggered by a menu button
Button("Print Documentation", action: {
                    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
                    printInfo.topMargin = 0.0
                    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
                    printInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
                    printInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
                    printInfo.paperSize = self.printInfo.paperSize
                    printInfo.orientation = self.printInfo.orientation
                    printInfo.scalingFactor = self.printInfo.scalingFactor
                    printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = false
                    printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = false
                    printInfo.scalingFactor = 1.0
                    
                    let rootView = Help.Preview(width: printInfo.paperSize.width)
                    let hostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: rootView)
                    
                    hostingView.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
                    let fittingSize = hostingView.fittingSize
                    hostingView.setFrameSize(fittingSize)
                    
                    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: hostingView, printInfo: printInfo)
                    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
                    printOperation.showsProgressPanel = true
                    
                    printOperation.run()
                } )

Any idea and help is appreciated.
I'v added a system image (printer), which works perfect. Although rendering the view in a window works fine,
